# Why did this user lose all his rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation, profile-page, users

I've seen this user before, and he normally has a high rep.  His profile serves to corroborate that, yet his current rep is only 81.  Upon closer inspection, I realized there are a TON of high-valued bounties.  Is this the result of a hacker, or something else?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/875317/b-clay-shannon

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/875317/b-clay-shannon?tab=reputation

Comment: I would assume either it's not a hack, or it's a very detailed one. A snippet from their about me: _"With that goal in mind, I am "pulling a Carnegie" with my Stack Overflow points, doling out bounties like there's no tomorrow."_ Along with something about a show about Mark Twain...

Comment: From the reputation history - this user has given a lot of their rep to bounties.

Comment: So you think someone would have to get hacked to want to post a bunch of bounties?

Comment: Many bounties placed? I think such was already asked recently.

Comment: @Kendra -- I see that now.  It was hidden by the picture at the top of the profile description.  Interesting.  Just curious.

Comment: @rory.ap A picture advertising the show, even. ;) But yes, looks like the user's just trying to keep their rep from going to waste before they go into showbiz.

Comment: @Servy -- your question implies cause and effect: "get hacked" --> results in --> "desire to post bounties".  Why would you think that's what I think?

Comment: @rory.ap You saw that someone posts a bunch of bounties, and as a result of just that, you assume they must have been hacked.  If you think that because they posted a lot of bounties they must have been hacked, then that means that you think that they wouldn't post said bounties without being hacked.  Unless there is an entirely unrelated reason you think that this user was hacked that you choose not to share, while also pointing out that this user posted a bunch of bounties knowing that it was unrelated, which I...doubt.

Comment: Interesting.  Like I said, I didn't look past the picture and now that I've scrolled I realize what it's all about.  Good luck to you, B. Clay Shannon.

Comment: Yes, I am "giving away the store" so to speak; one motivation is, for whatever reason I want my Duolingo points/rep (up to 3,995 now) to be greater than my SO rep; another is my quirky sense of humor is tickled by having as many gold badges as points. And yes, I am determined to make a go of this Twain interpretation "thing."

Comment: @B.ClayShannon -- Well, best of luck, sir.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon you're also 1/3 of the way to have all HTTP status codes for your badge counts.

Comment: @Gimby: I noticed the 404, but what are the others?

Comment: Seems like we have competition for leora for the most bounties offered. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/547794/top-20-most-generous-users-bounties-awarded

Comment: Damn, over 2000 questions asked, that's insane! Don't you ever do your own research?!

Comment: @B.ClayShannon (late response, somehow on meta I don't always see that someone tagged me) - 1/3 - one of three, the 404 is the one ;)

Comment: @DavidG doesn't seem like it. First thought, ask a question. Old style learning is too hard.

Comment: @Lankymart Almost 2300 questions now, it just blows my mind. And looking at the content of them, they're all so very simple too...

Comment: @DavidG I came across this because I raised a query about a question they had asked that assumed one language when they meant another, so then they are getting bad advice because people make assumptions. Just painful really... They may give their rep away as bounties but I still see them as the definition of a [hv](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19665/202529).

Comment: @Lankymart Indeed, giving away rep is just a smokescreen. I mean, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42798014/how-can-i-add-an-attachment-to-a-mailmessage) for example. How to add an attachment to a mail message, who would have guessed that the answer is `message.Attachments.Add`? Funnily enough I [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42821367/why-does-my-file-sometimes-disappear-in-the-process-of-reading-from-it-or-writin#comment72754585_42821367) him about this recently and he conveniently ignored my question :(